# mybatis oracle - ordering by the order of values in the IN clause using instr func

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

I wanna use the instr function to order the query results by the order of values in the IN clause.

mapper

```
public List<String> getFilePaths(@Param("ids") Integer[] ids)
```

xml

```
<select id="getFilePaths" resultType="java.lang.String">
  select filepath from t_file where id in
  <foreach item="fileid" collection="ids" separator="," open="(" close=")">
    #{fileid}
  </foreach>
  order by instr('
  <foreach item="fileid" collection="ids" separator=",">
    #{fileid}
  </foreach>
  ',id)
</select>
```

When the ids collection is [1, 2, 3], the sql generated by mybatis is:

```
select filepath from t_file where id in (?, ?, ?) order by instr('?, ?, ?', id)
```

But An exception occurs.

org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #4 with JdbcType null.

After changing the xml for testing like below, no exception occurs.

```
<select id="getFilePaths" resultType="java.lang.String">
  select filepath from t_file where id in
  <foreach item="fileid" collection="ids" separator="," open="(" close=")">
    #{fileid}
  </foreach>
  and id in
  <foreach item="fileid" collection="ids" separator="," open="(" close=")">
    #{fileid}
  </foreach>
</select>

Preparing: select filepath from t_file where id in (?, ?, ?) and id in (?, ?, ?)
Parameters: 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `#{}` in a literal. Use `${fileId}` in the second foreach loop.
Please see this [FAQ entry](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-difference-between--and-).

```xml
order by instr('
<foreach item="fileid" collection="ids" separator=",">
  ${fileid}
</foreach>
',id)
```

There may be some preconditions, but the sort logic seems unreliable.
When `ids` is `[222, 22, 2]`, for example, the `INSTR` will return the same value for all three rows.

Answer (score 0):

I wasted a couple of hours, trying to understand what is wrong in the code:

```
ORDER BY
<foreach item='item' index='index' collection='filter.sorting.sortingItem' open ='' separator=',' close=''>
      #{item.fieldName} #{item.sortingDirection}
</foreach>
```

And what I needed to do is just replace '#' with '$' !!!!!
Working result:

```
ORDER BY
<foreach item='item' index='index' collection='filter.sorting.sortingItem' open ='' separator=',' close=''>
     #{item.fieldName} #{item.sortingDirection}
</foreach>
```